# Complexity of cycle cancellation with integral capacities and irrational costs

Tags: ds.algorithms, optimization

Cycle cancellation is a standard textbook algorithm for computing minimum-cost circulations: As long as the residual graph of the current circulation contains a negative cycle, push as much flow along that cycle as possible.  I'm trying to understand the worst-case behavior of the generic algorithm.  For purposes of analysis, I want to assume that at each iteration, the negative cycle to augment is chosen *adversarially*.

If all capacities and costs are integers, each iteration decreases the cost of the current circulation by at least 1.  Thus, the algorithm halts after augmenting at most $-\$(f^*)$ cycles, where $\$(f^*)$ is the cost of the final circulation.  Moreover, standard bad examples for Ford-Fulkerson and the standard reduction from maximum flow to minimum-cost circulation imply that $-\$(f^*)$ iterations are necessary in the worst case.

If we allow irrational capacities, then standard bad examples of Ford-Fulkerson and the standard reduction from maximum flow to minimum-cost circulation imply that the algorithm may never terminate, and worse, may not even converge to an approximate minimum-cost circulation in the limit.

**What is known about the case of integer capacities and irrational costs?**  I have found nothing in the literature about this case.

Cycle cancelling must terminate after a finite number of iterations in this case, because there are only a finite number of feasible integer circulations, but that argument only implies the upper bound $O(U^E)$, where U is the maximum edge capacity.  [Zadeh's classical bad examples for network simplex](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01580132) (and I suspect [similar bad examples for Ford's generic shortest-path algorithm](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/086/jresv86n3p317_A1b.pdf)) imply an $\Omega(2^V)$ lower bound, even if the most negative cycle is canceled at each iteration.  Are any tighter bounds known?

In particular: What is known about the case of **unit** capacities and irrational costs?